# How to get instance data from mobiscroll when I click Save or Add button

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar, mobiscroll

[image: I am trying to get data when click add or save button click, also I want to save data to database from the calendar event last modified data.]

[here is my calendar link](https://docs.mobiscroll.com/5-26-2/javascript/eventcalendar#options;)

````
```
````

onEventUpdate: function (args) {

````
            var event = args.event;
            if (event.recurring) {
                originalRecurringEvent = args.oldEvent;
                eventOccurrence = args.oldEventOccurrence;
                if (args.isDelete) {
                    eventRecurringException = originalRecurringEvent.recurringException || [];
                    eventStart = eventOccurrence.start;
                    createRecurrenceEditPopup(true);
                } else {
                    createRecurrenceEditPopup(false);
                }
                return false;
            }
        }```
````